# How should I store multiple values into an SQL row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called **users**, and one of the rows needs to hold all the actions the user did, and the actions are referenced as `action_ids`.

How do I have the row hold multiple `action_ids`?

For example, lets say the user did 5 actions, each with IDs 100001, 100002, 100003, 100004, 100005. How do I store that into the database so I can later say all the actions a user did?

The row might have to store hundreds or thousands of 6 digit values.

Comment: You could use `implode` and `explode` or JSON.

Comment: @JCOC611: That's a bad idea since it can complicate otherwise simple queries. For example: Select rows that do not contain a specific value. You now have to implode that value in every single row. Also, you've missed an opportunity to index the field.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: you're right...I guess it depends on the specific use (if you don't need to do such queries, nor index the field, then it's an option; otherwise, creating a new table would be best).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend you create a `UserAction` table with a `UserId` and `ActionId`.  This way you could reference the actions done without having to store multiple values in one row of your `users` table.

You would store rows for each action a user takes.  The table might look like this:

```
SELECT ua.UserId, ua.ActionId
FROM UserAction AS ua
ORDER BY ua.UserId ASC, ua.ActionId ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Results:

```
1, 100001
1, 100002
1, 100007
2, 100002
2, 100003
```

Meaning that UserId = 1 performed actions 100001, 100002 and 100007 and UserId 2 performed 100002 and 100003

Doing this also helps preserve normalization for your database, making future queries easier as well.

You will be able to find how many actions have been performed by users easier (and other tasks) with this structure than parsing a column with text/string values: (I'm assuming you have a Name, or similar field)

```
SELECT u.Name, COUNT(1) AS NumberOfActionsPerformed
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN UserAction AS ua ON u.userId = ua.UserId
GROUP BY u.userId, u.Name 
ORDER BY NumberOfActionsPerformed DESC
```

Also, if I were making the table, I would add `UserActionId` as an Auto-incremental Id column to use as my `Primary Key`

Comment: That doesn't solve my question though, how should I be storing the potentially thousands of 6 digit values into the row ActionId like you suggest?

Comment: You create a row in the UserAction table for each action. Look up 'joining MySQL tables'

Comment: @MrMalayev I have updated my answer to show you what data in this table might look like.